# WCF Configuration problems: metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Service published to a site I am working on right now. Here is the development URL for the service: https://aspireportal.azurewebsites.net/BridgeService.svc

When I try to connect to the service using the Wcf Test Client, I get back the following error.

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   https://aspireportal.azurewebsites.net/BridgeService.svc If this is a
>   Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access,
>   please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the
>   specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please
>   refer to the MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error    URI: https://[redacted no longer needed]/BridgeService.svc
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'https://[redacted no longer needed]/BridgeService.svc'.    An
>   error occurred while making the HTTP request to
>   https://[redacted no longer needed]/BridgeService.svc. This could
>   be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured
>   properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by
>   a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server. 
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send.    Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.    An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote hostHTTP GET
>   Error    URI: https://[redacted no longer needed]/BridgeService.svc
>   There was an error downloading
>   'https://[redacted no longer needed]/BridgeService.svc'.    The
>   underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a
>   send.    Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.    An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

For reference, here is the relevant portion of my web.config file

```
<services>
  <service name="OnePortal.BridgeService">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
              contract="OnePortal.IBridgeService"/>

    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpsBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAddressVerify">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="[redacted by post]"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAddressVerify"
      contract="AddressService.IAddressVerify" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAddressVerify" />
</client>
```

And here are my service and classes.

```
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IBridgeService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        BridgeResponse AcceptBridgeRequest(BridgeRequest request);
    }
[DataContract]
    public class BridgeRequest 
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string AcordXML { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Vendor { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class BridgeResponse
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string ResponseXML { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool HasError { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }


    public class BridgeService : IBridgeService
    {



        public BridgeResponse AcceptBridgeRequest(BridgeRequest request)
        {


            return new BridgeResponse
            {
                HasError = false,
                ErrorMessage = string.Empty,
                ResponseXML = xml_response.OuterXml
            };


        }


    }
```

As you can see, all the classes are decorated appropriate, that I can tell. This kind of feels like the whole TLS1.2 thing that messed with everyone last year, but I seem to recall the error messages for that being more explicit about the TLS connection (unless I am mistaken.)

It is my hope that a fresh set of eyes can see what I am missing. TIA!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, its late and my brain isn't fully functional. I just whipped up a project, added the service reference, and it worked great. I think, possibly, this is the TLS1.2 thing and now that I think about I seem to recall that the WCF Test Client was maybe not super compliant with the new protocol.

I should have done this test before making my post.